# AVAssetExportSession SLOW

Tags: ios, audio, export, avfoundation

I am using AVAssetExportSession to export audio files. It is working, though in a speed that is practical for use. I am setting up my exporter, getting my AVAsset, and starting the export. Here is the code. Any suggestions or insight will help.

```
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"we are now exporting");
    int exportStatus = exporter.status;
    switch (exportStatus) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: {
            // log error to text view
            NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
            NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportError);
            break;
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
            NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
            // set up AVPlayer

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:exportURL];
            break;
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown"); break;}
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting"); break;}
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled"); break;}
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting"); break;}
        default: { NSLog (@"didn't get export status"); break;}
    }
    [exporter release];
    [exportURL release];
}];
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution without having to use AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably causing some kind of conversion - that will be slow (not that much faster than  realtime). Make sure you're using the passthrough preset, AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough.

Comment: so what does this specific preset do? Maybe you could help me out a little ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338498/avassetexportsession-using-avassetexportpresetpassthrough-breaking-output

Comment: Hi `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` does accelerate the conversion, but we're adding subtitles to our video, and using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` vs `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` or `AVAssetExportPresetHighQuality` causes the subtitles to go away. Is this expected behavior? The Apple docs are sparse, and there aren't any tutorials diving into what exactly `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` does. Thanks!

Comment: Has anybody found any solution to reduce time that exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() takes to export a video/audio. It takes a lot of time for me to encode large audios of length 5:00 and above.

Comment: any news @AliRaza? I am having the sam issues.