# AVAssetExportSession using AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough breaking output

Tags: avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm using AVAssetExportSession in combination with AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough to stitch multiple videos together. Everything works quite fine, except after my first sub-clip should have finished, it's picture "freezes" on the last frame but the second is not going to play. I made sure to set the layer opacity to 0.0f once each clip has finished, if I use another Preset-Type everything works...
Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got in touch with Apple, they told me this is a bug, please find the the bugreport here : https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/3/wo/zpx0I9jVzf8090ZICwg1GM/5.83.28.0.9

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

While you can use `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` to concatenate videos, the resulting video is not the most compatible as each segment ends up in its own track. It *should* play back in on iOS/OSX but it's unlikely to play nicely with YouTube or Facebook.

So there's something wrong with your implementation, but you should probably consider using a different preset (that will flatten your videos into one track) or use an `AVAssetWriter`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you provide me with some tips regarding the implementation? I would post some code but its a lot and I don't know whats relevant ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you are using a `AVMutableComposition` to insert 2 of your video clips by `insertTimeRange:ofAsset:atTime:error:`. This will result 2 video track on the composition, and when there're 2 video track and no composition layer instruction, only the first video track will be displayed. 
Try to alloc a video track yourself and insert the assets' video track to these video track using `insertTimeRange:ofTrack:atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error` will probably fix these issue.